# Excel 2013 VBA database connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a problem with VBA on Excel 2013.

I ask a parameter and than create a key for SQL but if I try to use it if I leave the string `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` I get a

> 1004 Runtime error

If I cut it, the transfer doesn't work ...any suggestions?

I wrote this code:

```vb
Bolla = InputBox("Numero Bolla?", "bolla", " ", 3000, 5000)

CHIAVE = "CCI " & bolla

Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = ("Trasferimento")

 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=CCI_DATV3;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        '.CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT §FIEB01L.NUDOS, §FIEB01L.RASCS, §FIEB01L.DASPS, §FIEB01L.DESTS, §FIEB01L.DEFIS, §FIEB01L.DESCS, §FIEB01L.QTISS, §FIEB01L.COSTS, §FIEB01L.BOBIS, §FIEB01L.TESIS, §FIEB01L.TESES, §FIEB01L.ORPRS FR" _
        , "OM CCI_DATV3.§FIEB01L WHERE ((§FIEB01L.NUDOS=" & CHIAVE & "))")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabella_Query_da_CCI_DATV3"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in the `.CommandText` property. Try setting it to:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT §FIEB01L.NUDOS, §FIEB01L.RASCS, §FIEB01L.DASPS, §FIEB01L.DESTS, §FIEB01L.DEFIS, §FIEB01L.DESCS, §FIEB01L.QTISS, §FIEB01L.COSTS, §FIEB01L.BOBIS, §FIEB01L.TESIS, §FIEB01L.TESES, §FIEB01L.ORPRS FROM CCI_DATV3.§FIEB01L WHERE §FIEB01L.NUDOS ='" & CHIAVE & "'"
```

I simply removed the `Array()` function, eliminated the comma after the line break and extra parentheses in the query. Given the fact that `CHIAVE` is a string, apostrophes were added to the query too.

Also, `.CommandType` should be be set to `xlCmdSql`

Let me know if that helps